# Loop through all schemas in Talend

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, talend

I am struggling with looping all schemas in Oracle.
What I need to achieve is as shown below

1. Create connection
2. Use the existing to fetch the schema tOracleInput2
3. tJavaRow to assign variable
4. tFlowToIterate for Iterations
5. Alter session based on schema fetched at step 2 using tOracleRow_1
6. Now i need to execute query and generate certain output and that will require one or more steps

But the issue is, that it will iterate till step 5 and when all the iterations are done, it moves to step 6. I want to add step 6 and more in the iterations so that it will run for 1 schema at a time.

[image: job description]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make `tOracleInput_1` part of the loop, you need to use `OnComponentOk` trigger like this :

[image: talend iterate oracle tjavarow]

Comment: :Will try in office tomorrow ,thanks alot you made my day

Comment: @GauravSoni You are welcome friend, im happy for that :)