# How to iterate over files for tMongoDBBulkLoad

Tags: mongodb, talend

What is the best way to iterate over files and feed them into tMongoDBBulkLoad?  It sees that you cannot feed into this component from a tFileList componet (Iterate) - which would make the most sense.

I want to import 80 files, rather than create one massive file which is too large to open in notepad if I have issues during the import.

Thanks

---Update----

I know how to do this with other components, my issue is I cannot feed an Iterate component into the tMongoBulkLoad

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplified job will be like this :

```
tFileList ---------iterate--------tMongoDBBulkLoad
```

and in the `tMongoDBBulkLoad` settings you set the `Data file` to :

```
((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEPATH"))
```

Here, the `tFileList` will iterate over files, in each iteration, the `tMongoDBBulkLoad` will be triggered to load the current file, which is indicated by the global variable.

--- Reply for the Update ---

To connect an iterate trigger to the component, you can add a dummy tjava with no code, it will be like this :

```
tFileList -----(iterate)-----tJava-------(onComponentOk)-------tMongoDBBulkLoad
```

Comment: Hi,  Thats my problem, the component doesnt accept an input from an Iterate component.  I added a screenshot to explain.

Comment: I dont have Talend instlled to try, but i think that works, see updates !

Comment: Its my understanding onComponentOK gets fired at the end of the entire iteration, not once per iteration - is that not the case?  https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=28781

Comment: no, oncomponentok will make the connected component part of the loop, see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34494429/2037229)

Comment: Will try, but the link I included in last comment has a similar set up and someone from Talend responded that tJava only gets fired off onComponentOK after the tFileList iteration has completed.  This was always my understanding.

Comment: @smackenzie: you are right for what in the link, but here is not the same case, here oncomponentok starting from tJava, but in your link its started from tFileList, and obviously, when the tFileList is ok the link is triggered !

Comment: whats the difference?  Why does onComponentOK fire when the entire iteration is done for one component, but after every execution for a tJava?  I am possibly being a bit stupid here ;-).  The name "onComponentOK" is not that helpful here...as is a component "OK" after it sends through one row of data, or when it finishes completely!

Comment: because, in case of tFileList, the component still starts, then loop is created and never stop until the loop is end, then the link triggered, but for tJava, the component is sarted and ended many times(because is part of a loop, so not always, just for this case), so for each time the link will triggered